# Apache ignite gives error when you refresh webpage

Tags: java, ignite

I'm new to apache ignite.

1. I have a java web project which gets results that are cached by apache ignite.
2. I have a separate project that starts and caches results from the database and starts a server node

When I load my web page the first time, all is good and it picks up my results. But if I refresh my page again it gives me an error saying:

> Default Ignite instance has already been started.

my code:

```
public MyConstructor() {
    Ignition.setClientMode(true);
    ignite = Ignition.start();
}
```

So what happens is when I refresh my page it loads the constructor everytime. Is there a better way to find if a node exists and use that? Or if there is a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Ignition.TryGetIgnite() ?? Ignition.Start()` construct to either get an existing instance or start a new one.

Comment: worked. thanks :) I removed it from the constructor and added it to my method instead. So Ignition.getOrStart wont create a new instance each time if already exists

Comment: I am having the same issue with Apache Ignite.Net for ASP.Net application. This fix doesn't work for me because Ignite.Net does not have the Ignition.getOrStart method. Is there a work around for ASP.Net?

Comment: @faitha I've edited the answer, there was a mistake. There is `TryGetIgnite` method.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn I tried the `TryGetIgnite` method but still doesn't work. The issue is that when the AppDomain restarts (for any reason), the running in-process Ignite can not be retrieved which means the app will try starting a new one and then throws `Default Ignite instance has already been started.` Do you have a working ASP.Net example?

Comment: @faitha See this question, looks like you are in the same situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363060/how-do-i-use-apache-ignite-from-two-or-more-iis-applications/