# How do I use Apache Ignite from two or more IIS applications

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis, ignite

I am new to Apache Ignite and trying to use Ignite within IIS websites and WCF services. My test case involves two IIS hosted WCF test services on one PC. I am instantiating Ignite in either of the two IIS applications and then trying to access from the other. So far this has not worked. Once Ignite starts in one IIS app, I get a "Default grid instance has already been started" from the other app, but the other app is not able to get a handle of the existing default grid instance.

I am running the code below from the Global.asax Application_Start of both IIS test applications. Hoping someone can give insight and point me in the right direction:

```
Random random = new Random();
short startCounter = 0;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
do
{
    Thread.Sleep( 1000 * random.Next( 10, 20 ) );
    IgniteEngine = Ignition.TryGetIgnite();
    startCounter++;
    if ( null == IgniteEngine )
    {
        LogHelper.Write( "{0}: CacheManager.InitializeCache attempt {1} to get a new ignite instance failed.".InvariantFormat( CommonSystemInfo.MachineName, startCounter ), "TraceLogger" );
    }

    if ( null == IgniteEngine )
    {
        try
        {
            IgniteEngine = Ignition.Start( new IgniteConfiguration
            {
                JvmClasspath = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles( System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath( @"~\bin\libs" ) ).Aggregate( ( x, y ) => x + ";" + y )
            } );
            if ( null != IgniteEngine )
            {
                LogHelper.Write( "{0}: CacheManager.InitializeCache success starting ignite after {1} attempts and {2} seconds".InvariantFormat( CommonSystemInfo.MachineName, startCounter, sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds ), "TraceLogger" );
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception ex2 )
        {
            LogHelper.Write( "{0}: CacheManager.InitializeCache error while trying to start a new ignite instance. {1}".InvariantFormat( CommonSystemInfo.MachineName, ex2.GetAllMessages() ), "TraceLogger" );
        }
    }
}
while ( null == IgniteEngine && sw.Elapsed.TotalMinutes <= 2 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your services run within one IIS Application Pool, which means one process and different app domains. This means that there is a single JVM within the process, which causes `Default grid instance has already been started` error.

Your options are:

- Use different `IgniteConfiguration.GridName`
- Assign different IIS Application Pool to one of the services
- Run both services within one application so that `TryGetIgnite` works and you don't have to start Ignite twice

Comment: Pavel, thanks for the guidance. I took the first two points above and it worked but only after an ugly discovery. I use the post-build step for asp.net deployment at https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/deployment#aspnet-deployment. This put jar files in the bin. Problems started after updating nuget from 1.7 to 1.8. The *.1.7 jar files had been copied into my bin folder and remained after the update. Subsequent publishing copied both 1.7 and 1.8 files to the deployment folder. The mix of 1.7 and 1.8 jars created problems. The post build needs a pre-build to erase previous files.

Comment: Possible pre-build step could be:

Comment: cd $(TargetDir)Libs
del *.jar